# Unity XmlDocument function not always working

Tags: c#, xmldocument, unity-game-engine, delayed-execution

Is there anything to consider when using XmlDocument function in unity3d?
I'm having this weird problem: When the function which uses XmlDocument is called from Awake() or OnGUI() the document is edited successfully. But when it's called from inside a button event, event tough I get a well edited string before saving the document, it's not able to modify the document itself.

Function that edits the file (sometimes):

```
    public static void addTestProfile () {

            string path = Application.dataPath + "/Documents/Profiles.xml";
            Hashtable tempTable = new Hashtable();
            tempTable.Add("user", "chuck II");
            tempTable.Add("url", "funny");
            tempTable.Add("passwrod", "1234asdf");
            General.StoreProfile(tempTable, path);
        }


public static void StoreProfile(Hashtable profile, string path) {
        Debug.Log("profile to store name: " + profile["password"]);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(profilesPath);

        XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement("Profile");

        XmlElement innerElement1 = doc.CreateElement("user");
        innerElement1.InnerText = profile["user"] as string;
        element.AppendChild(innerElement1);

        XmlElement innerElement2 = doc.CreateElement("url");
        innerElement2.InnerText = profile["url"] as string;
        element.AppendChild(innerElement2);

        XmlElement innerElement3 = doc.CreateElement("password");
        innerElement3.InnerText = profile["password"] as string;
        element.AppendChild(innerElement3);
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);

        doc.Save(profilesPath);
        Debug.Log(doc.InnerXml);
    }
```

**I created a new project just to test this problem, the file is not edited when called just before calling Application.loadLevel();**

Here it works well and the file itself is edited:

```
void OnGUI () {
         General.addTestProfile();  // General is the singleton class that contains the function implementation
}
```

But some how this is not working:

```
// GUI Save btn
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(255, 20, 60, 35), "Add")) {
      General.addTestProfile();   // General is the singleton class that contains the function implementation
      Application.LoadLevel(0);
}
```

When I print the resultant string right before the save() xmlDocument function, it shows the new item but somehow the xml file remains the same. 
Am I missing something important maybe related to the execution order? Something like  timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it jumped back to scene 1, it was re-writing the original file.

"Debug.Log" sucks! , this instruction never printed the second call to createProfilesFile() function. So just one line was missing:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(profilesPath)) return;
```

Here the createProfilesFile() function:

```
public static void CreateProfilesFile (string path) {
    Debug.Log("create init");      // This line wasn't called the second time ... 

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) return;

    // Create a new file specified path
    XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(path,null);
    // Opens the document
    textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    // Write comments
    textWriter.WriteComment("This document contains the profiles that have been created.");
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("Profiles");
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Profile");
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("user");
                textWriter.WriteString("foo user");
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("url");
                textWriter.WriteString("foo url");
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();       
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("password");
                textWriter.WriteString("foo password");
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();
    textWriter.WriteEndElement();
    // Ends the document.
    textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    // close writer
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: In either case I would not recommend performing file IO within the GUI loop. For most cases it is best to perform the function using a Coroutine of some form instead, as you have noticed the OnGUI call is called multiple times. Generally speaking you never which to perform anything which is not actually drawing the GUI in the OnGUI call directly.

Answer (score 1):

this is just a wild guess, but could this work?

```
// PSEUDOCODE
bool pressed

function OnGUI()
   if GUI.Button then
      pressed = true
   end if
   if pressed then
      addTestProfile();
   end if
end function
```

I took help from this link: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9538/new-to-unity-3d-gui-button-help-needed-please